# Anko CardView radius not work

Tags: android, kotlin, cardview, anko

I want to create cardView with anko and set cornerRadius param to it. But When I try to do - no such differents come.
In main class I do this:

```
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup): View {
    with(applicationContext!!) {
        listView = listView {
            layoutParams = ViewGroup.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
            dividerHeight = 20
        }
    }
    listView?.adapter = CustomAdapter(forms)

    return listView!!
}
```

In CustomAdapter I return cardView like this:

```
override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup?): View {
    val currentForm = getItem(position)
    return convertView ?: createCardView(parent!!.context, currentForm)
}

private fun createCardView(context: Context, form: FormField): View =
        with(context) {
            frameLayout {
                cardView {
                    layoutParams = FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT).apply {
                        leftMargin = dip(10)
                        rightMargin = dip(10)
                        topMargin = dip(5)
                        bottomMargin = dip(5)

                    }
                    backgroundColor = Color.WHITE
                    radius = dip(8).toFloat()

                    verticalLayout {
                        // title
                        textView {
                            text = form.title
                            textColor = ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.colorPrimary)
                            textSize = 20f
                        }.lparams(width = matchParent) {
                            leftMargin = dip(15)
                            topMargin = dip(10)
                            bottomMargin = dip(10)
                        }
                        // subtitle
                        textView {
                            if (form.subTitle != null) {
                                text = form.subTitle
                                textColor = ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.colorPrimary)
                                textSize = 12f
                                visibility = View.VISIBLE
                            } else {
                                visibility = View.GONE
                            }
                        }.lparams(width = matchParent) {
                            leftMargin = dip(15)
                            topMargin = dip(10)
                            bottomMargin = dip(10)
                        }

                    }.lparams(width = matchParent, height = matchParent)
                }
            }
        }
```

I try to call 'radius' setter in different ways and values, but result is always like this
[image]

As you can see - the corners are always rectangle. What I want - to round the corners with Anko 
[image]

Small p.s. - when I return from `getView` inflated xml layout with same cardview - it has rounded corners.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So, the problem was in

```
backgroundColor = Color.WHITE
```

It was set the default background DRAWABLE param to ColorDrawable instead inner `RoundRectDrawable`.
So, when I change this row to :

```
background.setColorFilter(Color.WHITE, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP)
```

All start to work and corners become to be rounded

Answer (score 2):

The previous answer didn't help me. That is worked for me:

```
cardView {    
    background = GradientDrawable().apply {
        shape = GradientDrawable.RECTANGLE
        cornerRadius = 8f
        setStroke(2, grey)
        ....
    }
}
```